# Invalid indexing operation error when trying to draw epipolar lines

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-cvst, stereoscopy

I'm creating Stereo images processing project modeled on Matlab's examples. A copy pasted code from one of them don't works well.

```
I1 = rgb2gray(imread('viprectification_deskLeft.png'));
I2 = rgb2gray(imread('viprectification_deskRight.png'));

points1 = detectHarrisFeatures(I1);
points2 = detectHarrisFeatures(I2);

[features1, valid_points1] = extractFeatures(I1, points1);
[features2, valid_points2] = extractFeatures(I2, points2);

indexPairs = matchFeatures(features1, features2);

matchedPoints1 = valid_points1(indexPairs(:, 1),:);
matchedPoints2 = valid_points2(indexPairs(:, 2),:);

figure; showMatchedFeatures(I1, I2, matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2);
load stereoPointPairs

[fLMedS, inliers] = estimateFundamentalMatrix(matchedPoints1,matchedPoints2,'NumTrials',4000);

figure;
subplot(121); imshow(I1);
title('Inliers and Epipolar Lines in First Image'); hold on;
plot(matchedPoints1(inliers,1), matchedPoints1(inliers,2), 'go');
```

An error:

Error using epilineTest (line 24) Invalid indexing operation.

Best regards

Comment: Please include the full error sack. Which line calls `epilineTest`?

Comment: @Daniel epilineTest is a name of file, which includes this code (epilineTest.m). Full content of error is as I written:
<>
Error using epilineTest (line 24)
Invalid indexing operation.
<>
And nothing more

Comment: Which line is line 24? Your code has less than 24 lines.

Comment: The error is in last line (23 or 24, maybe one paragraph disappeared, someone can get different index of the last line's error).
This is a whole code included in epilineTest.m of course.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an older version of MATLAB.  Try doing this:

```
[fLMedS, inliers] = estimateFundamentalMatrix(...
      matchedPoints1.Location, matchedPoints2.Location,'NumTrials',4000);
```

Generally, look at the example in your own local MATLAB documentation, rather than the one on the website.  The website has the doc for the latest release (currently R2014a), and the examples may be using new features that do not exist in the older versions.